# How to deploy ASP Web API to IIS using FTP?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have developed ASP REST Web API and everything works correctly during on localhost. This is how I get my api request on localhost:

http://localhost:59547/api/JSMachines

Now I have to deploy this api to IIS server and I don't have the access to the server. I was only given the FTP credentials to connect to the server. The IIS is said to be IIS 7 with windows web server 2008. This is the files in the server.

[image]

I uploaded my project files and dll to wwwroot.

[image]

Now I am trying to access the api but I keep getting 404 - Not Found.

This is how I get the api request on server.

http://www.rocketserver.com/api/JSMachines

Within the web api project also, I have some html pages to show some records which also using the same dlls as my api and it works correctly on both localhost and server. Only the web api requests is returning me 404 error.

Comment: In Visual Studio you can publish the project directly to an ftp server.

Comment: I have tried that also, but still no luck.

Comment: The client does not have the credentials to read/write on the IIS.  To be able to access the dll you would need to put the api in a application and set the app to run as an admin for the clients to access the api.